# Headset problem after Xbox One Update

Tags: xbox-one

Ok. So before the windows 10 update (or whatever it is) when I had my headset plugged in and controller was running low, all I had to do was to switch to a new controller. Then I click on my profile and it's connected. Well since the update I haven't figured a way to get my headset to register that I'm on a new controller. I can hear everyone thorough my headset but they can only hear me through my Kinect.

Comment: Happened recently. Plug it in more. Possibly?

Comment: I've unplugged and plugged it back in multiple times still won't won't connect. Only way is for me to sign off and sign back in, or turn reset my console.

Comment: Have you updated the controller?

Comment: Have you tried switching the option to use your Kinect as microphone to "off"?